# How can I include an HTML <template> element within a Meteor Blaze Template?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-blaze, html5-template

I'm using Meteor, but would like to use some vanilla javascript/HTML code that uses the html template element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

When I try to include one inside a meteor template:

```
<template name="test2">
    <template id="test3">Some stuff i will clone in javascript</template>
</template>
```

Meteor displays the following error:

```
While processing files with templating (for target web.browser):
client/index.html:153: Expected one of: <body>, <head>, <template>
```

Is there a way to include these in a Meteor template? I am aware I can include them within the body tag but its a bit unwieldy.

Comment: Are you specifically interested in embedding a template tag or are you just trying to call a subtemplate?

Comment: Specifically interested in embedding a template tag that I can query, clone, etc, using standard javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper

**In a client side .js file**

```
Template.registerHelper('vanillaTemplate', () => {
    return '<template id="test3">Some stuff i will clone in javascript</template>'
})
```

**In a client side .html file**

```
<template name="test2">
    {{> vanillaTemplate}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

afaict this can't be done in Meteor because Meteor uses the template tag for exactly the reason it was designed, from your link:

> The HTML template element  is a mechanism for holding
>   client-side content that is not to be rendered when a page is loaded
>   but may subsequently be instantiated during runtime using JavaScript.

You should never see a `<template>` tag actually appear in the DOM which will preclude you from manipulating it in the DOM later.

It sounds like you maybe trying to do something that Blaze itself has assumed responsibility for. Perhaps you can tell us what you want to do with your template and we can tell you how to do it in Meteor.

Comment: Oh I just have some libraries that use HTML template, I imagine i could write some code to port them over, but easier to just stick them as a big clump in the body element. Would have been nice to have broken them up into seperate files though.

Comment: This might also simply be an edge case not properly handled by Blaze. As described in [their doc](https://github.com/meteor/blaze/tree/master/packages/templating-tools#templatingtoolsscanhtmlfortagsoptions): "_Scan an HTML file for top-level tags_" whereas it catches the closing tag of the child `<template>` instead of looking for the top-level closing tag. A new demonstration of [how hard it is to parse HTML with RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Raised [issue meteor/blaze #286](https://github.com/meteor/blaze/issues/286) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of providing an alternative solution, depending on what your 3rd party library needs as HTML template, you can also use `<script type="text/x-template">` instead of the new `<template>`:

```html
<template name="test2">
    <script type="text/x-template" id="test3">
        Some stuff i will clone in javascript
    </script>
</template>
```

For example, this was [the typical solution for Vue](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/03/24/vue-js-component-templates/) before `<template>` was widely supported by browsers.

The advantage is that you keep layout declaration in your HTML, and you have total freedom in adjusting its content, instead of having to register a helper for each variation.

Most IDE's also natively support code syntax highlighting in such code blocks, whereas much fewer of them do it for HTML in strings.